# how to do calculations in loop without ui lag in the flutter?

Tags: flutter, performance, dart

I have 1000+ models in memory now if I change something in the UI and UI it totally depends on these models. now I can not use the for loop in the main UI isolate because it would make UI laggy but I still need to change the values of the models how can I do this?

I have thought that I could use a different isolate and do calculations in the new isolate but I still need to get those changed values in the main isolate right using port. getting values from the different isolates will slow things too?

Comment: Maybe you can simulate the flow first then can estimate the execution time whether is optimise or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using a separate isolate for heavy computations and updating UI asynchronously is a good strategy to prevent the main UI thread from becoming laggy. However, communication between isolates involves message passing, and it can introduce some overhead.

Here i'm demonstrating the isolate with don't communicates, calculates values
exits isolate and pass them back to the main thread, This way you can update the UI after the isolate gets completed.

```
  void _parallelOp() async {
    try {
      // Receive port.
      ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();

      // Creating a new tread or isolate in flutter terms.
      await Isolate.spawn(ParallelOperation.parallelOp, {
        AppConsts.sendPort: receivePort.sendPort,
        // pass models that used in the calculation
        // or requires modifications
        // as key value pair.
      });

      // updated values/models.
      final Map<String, dynamic> foo = await receivePort.first;
    } catch (e) {
      await Future.error(StringConsts.errorInParallelOperation);
    }
  }
```

And method for isolate will be defined as below, remember that the isolate method need to be a different class having the isolate generating method.

```
class ParallelOperation {
  /// [parallelOp] do the parallel computing.
  static Future<void> parallelOp(Map<String, dynamic> args) async {
   
    // retrieve your models.
    final dynamic model = args['key'];
    
    // Do the computation or modification.

    /// Exiting the isolate,
    /// as all the operations are completed.
    /// pass direct model or map having multiple values and model.
    Isolate.exit(args[AppConsts.sendPort], model);
  }
}
```

For sending data in the running isolate you need to listen the receivePort and send data with sendPort from the isolate.